# How to filter data using wildcard parameter along with other parameters?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, wildcard

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcName 
    @IsMatch varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT
        IMS_PolicyNumber, Rater_PolicyNumber
    FROM
        tblPolicies 
    WHERE
        (@IsMatch = 'No Match' AND Rater_PolicyNumber <> IMS_PolicyNumber OR Rater_PolicyNumber IS NULL) -- returns No Match records
        OR (@IsMatch = 'Match' AND Rater_PolicyNumber = IMS_PolicyNumber) --Returns Matching Records
        OR (@IsMatch = 'Both') --Returns both: matching and no matching records
```

But now I want to add wildcard parameter `@Rater_PolicyNumber` so user will be able to just enter first letters of the `Rater_PolicyNumber` and filter the result or if user leave it blank, then just ignore this parameter:

```
AND @Rater_PolicyNumber LIKE COALESCE('%'+ @Rater_PolicyNumber+'%','')
```

But I'm having a hard time to get it work along with `@IsMatch` parameter:

The below works if I pass value in `@Rater_PolicyNumber`, but if I leave it blank - it returns all the records, instead of just non matching records.

```
WHERE
    ((@IsMatch = 'No Match' AND Rater_PolicyNumber <> IMS_PolicyNumber OR Rater_PolicyNumber is null) 
     OR Rater_PolicyNumber LIKE COALESCE('%'+ @Rater_PolicyNumber+'%',''))
```

How can I return 'No Match', 'Match' and 'Both' records and also filter them by `@Rater_PolicyNumber` value ONLY if user will enter it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get tricky working with multiple `and` and `or`. I have applied some formatting and added parenthesis around the sections to return the records as they were being returned originally, but if `@Rater_PolicyNumber` is not null, it also applies the `like`.

```
select IMS_PolicyNumber
  , Rater_PolicyNumber
from tblPolicies 
where (
       Rater_PolicyNumber like '%'+ @Rater_PolicyNumber+'%'
       or Rater_PolicyNumber is null
       or @Rater_PolicyNumber is null 
      )
  and (
        (@IsMatch = 'No Match' 
         and (Rater_PolicyNumber<>IMS_PolicyNumber 
              or Rater_PolicyNumber is null) 
          )
      -- returns No Match records
       or (@IsMatch= 'Match' and Rater_PolicyNumber=IMS_PolicyNumber) 
      -- Returns Matching Records
       or (@IsMatch = 'Both') 
      --Returns both: matching and no matching records 
      )
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it doesnt return NULL values if `Rater_PolicyNumber = NULL` and I need those too. Do you think its possible?

Comment: @Oleg Updated to include `or Rater_PolicyNumber is null` in the first set of criteria

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect! Sorry for the delay!!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
        SELECT
            IMS_PolicyNumber, Rater_PolicyNumber
        FROM
            tblPolicies 
        WHERE CHARINDEX(@IsMatch,CASE WHEN  Rater_PolicyNumber = IMS_PolicyNumber THEN 'Match,Both' ELSE 'No MATCH,Both' END)>0
```